# Change tag to gallery

Tags: php, str-replace

I need to replace tag [gallery-1] in variable from database to actual gallery. Problem is, that that gallery is stated by that number in tag (i have multiple galleries or categories whatever). I tried str_replace, but it doesn't solve problem with number.
I need to take that number, select images from gallery number X and than echo them (replace with content depending on that number).

Comment: `str_replace('gallery-', '', $gallery);` should work without the brackets

Answer (score 1):

[preg_match_all()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) is your friend:

```
$code = "<p>Test...test...test...</p> [gallery-1]";

preg_match_all("/\[gallery-(\d+)\]/", $code, $matches);

$galleries = array();

foreach ($matches[1] as $id) {
  $galleries[$id] = // Somehow load a gallery basing on id;
}

foreach ($galleries as $id => $c) {
  $code = str_ireplace("[gallery-" . $id . "]", $c, $code);
}

echo $code;
```

If you are still confised, here's [an example](http://ideone.com/Em9ybl).

Comment: Do you mean `foreach`?

Comment: Well this looks good, but it doesn't work. for should be foreach here ?? and $galleries = []; doesn't work too. I changed it to $galleries =  array(), but it returns nothing. I personally don't know, how that second foreach works (that with 3 variables), bud there should be a problem (or i get it all wrong).

Comment: Also, `str_ireplace` needs to be changed into `$code = str_ireplace("[gallery-" . $id . "]", $c, $code);`

Comment: @ßluray, `$id` and `$c` stand for keys and values of items inside the array.

Comment: @FelipeFrancisco, Yes with that little update it works pretty well now

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the integer from the string `[gallery-1]` (including the brackets) try this :

```
$gallery = '[gallery-1]';
echo preg_replace('/\[gallery-(\d+)\]/', '$1', $gallery);
```

Comment: when going with the preg* route, might as well go with \d thus
preg_replace('/\[gallery-(\d+)\]/', '$1', $gallery);